# numpy seems return wrong eigenvector for circular matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am using numpy to calculate the eigenvalue and eigenvector of a circular matrix. Here is my code(Hji for j=1,2...6 is predefined):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> H = np.array([H1i, H2i, H3i, H4i, H5i, H6i])
>>> H
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
>>> from numpy import linalg as LA
>>> w, v = LA.eig(H)

>>> w
array([-2.,  2.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.])
>>> v
array([[ 0.40824829, -0.40824829, -0.57735027,  0.57732307,  0.06604706,
         0.09791921],
       [-0.40824829, -0.40824829, -0.28867513, -0.29351503, -0.5297411 ,
        -0.4437968 ],
       [ 0.40824829, -0.40824829,  0.28867513, -0.28380804,  0.46369403,
        -0.54171601],
       [-0.40824829, -0.40824829,  0.57735027,  0.57732307,  0.06604706,
        -0.09791921],
       [ 0.40824829, -0.40824829,  0.28867513, -0.29351503, -0.5297411 ,
         0.4437968 ],
       [-0.40824829, -0.40824829, -0.28867513, -0.28380804,  0.46369403,
         0.54171601]])
```

The eigenvalues are correct. However, for the eigenvector, I found out they are not linearly independent

```
>>> V = np.zeros((6,6))
>>> for i in range(6):
...     for j in range(6):
...         V[i,j] = np.dot(v[:,i], v[:,j])
... 

>>> V
array([[  1.00000000e+00,  -2.77555756e-17,  -2.49800181e-16,
         -3.19189120e-16,  -1.11022302e-16,   2.77555756e-17],
       [ -2.77555756e-17,   1.00000000e+00,  -1.24900090e-16,
         -1.11022302e-16,  -8.32667268e-17,   0.00000000e+00],
       [ -2.49800181e-16,  -1.24900090e-16,   1.00000000e+00,
         -1.52655666e-16,   8.32667268e-17,  -1.69601044e-01],
       [ -3.19189120e-16,  -1.11022302e-16,  -1.52655666e-16,
          1.00000000e+00,   1.24034735e-01,  -8.32667268e-17],
       [ -1.11022302e-16,  -8.32667268e-17,   8.32667268e-17,
          1.24034735e-01,   1.00000000e+00,  -1.66533454e-16],
       [  2.77555756e-17,   0.00000000e+00,  -1.69601044e-01,
         -8.32667268e-17,  -1.66533454e-16,   1.00000000e+00]])
>>>
```

You can see there are off-diagonal terms(check V[2,5] = -1.69601044e-01) which means they are not linear independent vectors. Since this is a Hermitian matrix, how can its eigenvectors become dependent?

By the way, I also use matlab to calculate it and it returns the right value

```
V =

    0.4082   -0.2887   -0.5000    0.5000    0.2887   -0.4082
   -0.4082   -0.2887    0.5000    0.5000   -0.2887   -0.4082
    0.4082    0.5774         0         0   -0.5774   -0.4082
   -0.4082   -0.2887   -0.5000   -0.5000   -0.2887   -0.4082
    0.4082   -0.2887    0.5000   -0.5000    0.2887   -0.4082
   -0.4082    0.5774         0         0    0.5774   -0.4082


D =

   -2.0000         0         0         0         0         0
         0   -1.0000         0         0         0         0
         0         0   -1.0000         0         0         0
         0         0         0    1.0000         0         0
         0         0         0         0    1.0000         0
         0         0         0         0         0    2.0000
```

Comment: The off-diagonal terms are roughly 0.0000000000000001.  They are just "rounding errors" due to the imprecision of floating point math.

Comment: @BrenBarn. Sorry I did not make it clear, you can check V[2,5] = -1.69601044e-01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Hermitian and symmetric matrices you should use another function: `eigh`.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA

H = np.array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])

w, v = LA.eigh(H)

V = np.zeros((6,6))
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        V[i,j] = np.dot(v[:,i], v[:,j])

w
Out[19]: array([-2., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  2.])

v
Out[20]: 
array([[-0.40824829, -0.57735027,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.57735027,
         0.40824829],
       [ 0.40824829,  0.28867513, -0.5       , -0.5       ,  0.28867513,
         0.40824829],
       [-0.40824829,  0.28867513,  0.5       , -0.5       , -0.28867513,
         0.40824829],
       [ 0.40824829, -0.57735027,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.57735027,
         0.40824829],
       [-0.40824829,  0.28867513, -0.5       ,  0.5       , -0.28867513,
         0.40824829],
       [ 0.40824829,  0.28867513,  0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.28867513,
         0.40824829]])

V
Out[21]: 
array([[  1.00000000e+00,   8.32667268e-17,   2.77555756e-17,
          8.32667268e-17,  -2.08166817e-16,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  8.32667268e-17,   1.00000000e+00,   5.55111512e-17,
          5.55111512e-17,  -2.22044605e-16,  -1.11022302e-16],
       [  2.77555756e-17,   5.55111512e-17,   1.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   2.77555756e-17,   1.11022302e-16],
       [  8.32667268e-17,   5.55111512e-17,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.00000000e+00,   8.32667268e-17,   5.55111512e-17],
       [ -2.08166817e-16,  -2.22044605e-16,   2.77555756e-17,
          8.32667268e-17,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,  -1.11022302e-16,   1.11022302e-16,
          5.55111512e-17,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00]])
```

Comment: @Aaron There are different algorithms used for computation. From numpy docs: `eig` "is implemented using the _geev LAPACK routines" and `eigh` - "using LAPACK routines _syevd, _heevd". Shortly about differences you can read on Intel site: [Symmetric](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/521045) and [Nonsymmetric](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/521079) Eigenvalue Problems. If you want deeper information, read about [Lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

The result returned by `eig` is perfectly fine. This can be seen by

```
np.allclose(v.dot(np.diag(w)).dot(LA.inv(v)),H)
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Note that the output of `eig` corresponds to a factorization of the input matrix of the form `v * diag(w) * inv(v)`, which holds for generic diagonalizable matrices. Since `eig` treats `H` as having no special structure the returned eigenvectors are not expected to have a special structure, e.g., orthogonal. (Do not confuse orthogonality with linear independence - the columns of `v` are indeed linearly independent as can be simply verified by the non-zero `LA.det(v)`.)

Function `eigh` knows that the input matrix is hermitian and returns a more convenient, i.e., orthogonal, set of eigenvectors.

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood the definition of linear independence and orthogonality. The eigtenvector of a Hermitian matrix should be linear independent from each other but liner independence does not imply orthogonality(orthogonality implies linear independence).